# Mybatis - multiple base package in mapperscan?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

How to configure multiple base packages for mapperconfigurer.

We tried giving comma separated/ semi colon to put multiple base packages.

```
@Bean
public MapperScannerConfigurer mapper1(Environment env)
throws Exception
{
  MapperScannerConfigurer mapper = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
  mapper.setBasePackage("co.test1.event.mapper1,co.test2.event.mapper2");
  return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the command with space, what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the following Java doc I found in ConfigurableApplicationContext.java

```
/**
     * Any number of these characters are considered delimiters between
     * multiple context config paths in a single String value.
     * @see org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext#setConfigLocation
     * @see org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader#CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#setContextConfigLocation
     */
    String CONFIG_LOCATION_DELIMITERS = ",; \t\n";
```

The reason I brought this up is, I found the following line in MapperScannerConfigurer#postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry

```
scanner.scan(StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(this.basePackage, ConfigurableApplicationContext.CONFIG_LOCATION_DELIMITERS));
```

I think I made my point. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should try below with annotations to configure multiple base packages:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan({"com.transactions.persistence.mapper","com.transactions2.persistence.mapper"})
public class MyBatisConfig {
...
...
}
```